# Timed start objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, timed

I want to make a program that play sound in every hour but im stuck.I need some help to solve the problem, and that problem is that i dont know how to tell the program to play a sound in every hour.Im trying with some compare (i set the date to an integer and compare with an other integer), but this doesent seems to work...Can anybody help?(for ex.: i want that the NSDate plays me the sound az 13:00)Many thanx

Answer (score 2):

`NSTimer` is ok if you know the iOS app will be in the foreground when the timer expires. However to be more robust you'd need to use [local nofications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play a sound at a specified time without your app running in the foreground you'll have to use notifications:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = <some hour in the future>;
localNotif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
localNotif.soundName = @"soundFile.caf";
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

The sound file has to be part of your application main bundle though and you can't use arbritary sound files.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

See [Creating and Scheduling a Timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an : NSTimer

This [tutorial](http://www.osxfaq.com/Tutorials/cocoa/index5.ws) could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSTimer`.

Setup `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc]initWithFireDate:<your_start_date> 
                     interval:(60 * 60)  
                     target:self 
                     selector:@selector(timerHandler:) 
                     userInfo:nil 
                     repeats:YES];
```

and write your handler..

```
-(void)timerHandler:(NSTimer*)timer{
 //play your sound here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTimerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)myTimerMethod
{
//Play an Alarm
}
```